# Does anyone know a regexp to extract just the video id from a Vimeo embed using php? 

Tags: php, regex, vimeo

Does anyone know a regexp to extract just the video id from a Vimeo `<embed>` tag using php?

eg:

```
13084859
```

from:

```
<object width="400" height="225"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="225"></embed></object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
$html = '<object width="400" height="225"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="225"></embed></object>';

if (preg_match('/moogaloop\.swf\?clip_id=([0-9]+)/', $html, $matches)) {
  echo $matches[1];
} else {
  echo 'n/a';
}
```

Comment: that's perfect. you've saved my weekend ;)

Comment: older version of the embed code work with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087681/youtube-vimeo-video-id-from-embed-code-or-from-url-with-php-regular-expression-re

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function I've written for you, is working fine, but its not using regex :)

```
<?php
function get_vimeo_id( $embed )
{
    $vimeo_id_array = explode( '?clip_id=', $embed );
    $vimeo_id_array_2 = explode( '&amp;', $vimeo_id_array[1] );
    $vimeo_id = $vimeo_id_array_2[0];

    return $vimeo_id;
}

// Get Vimeo Id
$vimeo_id = get_vimeo_id( '<object width="400" height="225"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=13084859&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="225"></embed></object>' );

// Use $vimeo_id
echo $vimeo_id;
?>
```

Comment: awesome. really needed it as regex this time, but I'll certainly make a note of this for future use.