# YouTube Vimeo Video ID from Embed Code or From URL with PHP Regular Expression RegEx

Tags: php, regex, youtube, vimeo

I want to get Video ID for YouTube or Vimeo via its Embed code or from URL, Any solution to do this with PHP ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the IDs. I will cover the expressions themselves later in this answer, but here is the basic idea of how to use preg_match:

```
preg_match('expression(video_id)', "http://www.your.url.here", $matches);
$video_id = $matches[1];
```

---

Here is a breakdown of the expressions for each type of possible input you asked about. I included a link for each showing some test cases and the results.

1. For **YouTube URLs** such as `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89OpN_277yY`, you could use [this](http://rubular.com/r/UkdKjNY1fp) expression:

   ```
   v=(.{11})
   ```
2. **YouTube embed codes** can either look like this (some extraneous stuff clipped):

   ```
   <object width="640" height="390">
       <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/89OpN_277yY?fs=...
       ...
   </object>
   ```

   Or like this:

   ```
   <iframe ... src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/89OpN_277yY" ... </iframe>
   ```

   So an expression to get the ID from either style would be [this](http://rubular.com/r/oDA5CL9HIS):

   ```
   \/v\/(.{11})|\/embed\/(.{11})
   ```
3. **Vimeo URLs** look like `http://vimeo.com/<integer>`, as far as I can tell. The lowest I found was simply `http://vimeo.com/2`, and I don't know if there's an upper limit, but I'll assume for now that it's limited to 10 digits. Hopefully someone can correct me if they are aware of the details. [This](http://rubular.com/r/zlNyWzuNmP) expression could be used:

   ```
   vimeo\.com\/([0-9]{1,10})
   ```
4. **Vimeo embed** code takes this form:

   ```
   <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<integer>" width="400" ...
   ```

   So you could use [this](http://rubular.com/r/csRdUcWfiQ) expression:

   ```
   player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/([0-9]{1,10})
   ```

   Alternately, if the length of the numbers may eventually exceed 10, you could use:

   ```
   player\.vimeo\.com\/video/([0-9]*)"
   ```

   Bear in mind that the `"` will need to be escaped with a `\` if you are enclosing the expression in double quotes.

---

**In summary**, I'm not sure how you wanted to implement this, but you could either combine all expressions with `|`, or you could match each one separately. Add a comment to this answer if you want me to provide further details on how to combine the expressions.

Comment: I don't seem to get any matches when I use these regexes with preg_match. Should I have to modify them in some way or is the regex flavor different?

Comment: Dont forget / delimiters. For example for Vimeo use:

    preg_match('/player\.vimeo\.com\/video\/([0-9]{1,10})/', "your.url.here", $matches);
    $video_id = $matches[1];

Answer (score 2):

There is another similar [for youtube only] answered here, might be useful to have a look.
[PHP Regex to get youtube video ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id)

Answer (score 2):

There is another question with a lot of good answers, specifically from @user2200660.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16841070/3850405

I prefer to use a regex that both can handle embedded code or any URL currently used.

```
http://vimeo.com/423630
https://vimeo.com/1399176
http://vimeo.com/423630087
https://vimeo.com/423630087
https://player.vimeo.com/video/423630087
https://player.vimeo.com/video/423630087?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0
https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/423630087
https://vimeo.com/showcase/7008490/video/407943692
```

Regex that can handle all URLs I have come across:

```
(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/?(showcase\/)*([0-9))([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/p2Kldc/1/

```
$vimeo = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/67019023';

if(preg_match("/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/?(showcase\/)*([0-9))([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/", $vimeo, $output_array)) {
    echo "Vimeo ID: $output_array[6]";
}
```

Credits to @zeckdude for the original example code in PHP.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860052/3850405

JavaScript version:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65846269/3850405

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest youtube standard, you can use following code to extract video id from embed code.

```
$embed = '<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/n6WYu-pSXH8" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
preg_match('~embed/(.*?)"~', $embed, $output);
echo $output[1];
```

Thank you